# Lua preserving global values

Tags: c++, lua

I use Lua for my game engine logic. My main game loop is not done in Lua. Only special nodes in my scene hierarchy have Lua scripts attached. These scripts are executed every frame. The problem I face is that I need to keep global variable values from one frame to another.

My temporary solution looks like this:

```
finish = useBool("finish", false)
timer = useInt("timer", 0)
showTimer = useBool("showTimer", true)
startTimer = useInt("startTimer", 0)
play0 = useBool("play0", false)
play1 = useBool("play1", false)
play2 = useBool("play2", false)
play3 = useBool("play3", false)
delta = useInt("delta", 0)
gameOverTime = useInt("gameOverTime", 5000)
finishTime = useInt("finishTime", 5000)
checkPoint = useInt("checkPoint", 255)

<...> Game logic <...>

setInt("message", message);
setInt("checkPoint", checkPoint)
setInt("finishTime", finishTime)
setInt("gameOverTime", gameOverTime)
setInt("timer", timer)
setBool("play3", play3)
setBool("play2", play2)
setBool("play1", play1)
setBool("play0", play0)
setInt("startTimer", startTimer)
setBool("showTimer", showTimer)
setInt("timer", timer)
setBool("finish", finish);
```

I call special methods that retrieve global variables from hash maps in C++ at the beginning and I set them again at the end of the script.

Is there a way to do this implicitly?

Is it a bad design to use Lua not as the main game loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, while there is nothing technically wrong with your solution, you might start to notice some performance issues if you end up with a lot of global variables (something you should, in general, avoid).

With that said, there is room for improvement. For example:

At the beginning of the script, check if your global variable is `nil`. If it is, then you can initialize it, if not, this is probably not the first time you're running the script, so leave it unmodified. But that means a lot of pesky `if-else` statements, which one can easily forget about. We can do better!

I would recommend looking at [Chapter 14: The Environment](http://www.lua.org/pil/14.html), from the Programming in Lua book. Here's a quick quote from the intro:

> Lua keeps all its global variables in a regular table, called the environment. ... The other (actually the main) advantage is that we can manipulate this table as any other table. To facilitate such manipulations, Lua stores the environment itself in a global variable _G. (Yes, _G._G is equal to _G.)

Since `_G` is a table, it also has a metatable, so you can define `__index` and `__newindex` metamethods to handle access to and creation of global variables. You can find examples of this in [section 14.2](http://www.lua.org/pil/14.2.html). Go read the whole chapter, it's not that long (if you're unfamiliar with metamethods and metatables, also look through [chapter 13](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.html) - this is where Lua really shines in terms of flexibility).

Now that we've covered the trivial and normal methods, let's look at the overkill end of the spectrum. As an example I'll look at Unity's approach to scripting. A Unity javascript usually defines variables, functions, and types. Any variables defined outside of the scope of methods or types are persisted between frames because the script itself is not executed every frame. Instead, they let the script define functions and call the functions at the appropriate time. So if you want something executed every frame - you put it in the `Update` function. Every script can define it's own `Update` function because it has it's own scope. So every frame the scripting engine goes through all objects, checks if the script's scope has an `Update` method and calls it.

Back to Lua - a solution like this would involve creating separate environments for each object/script/whatever your node is. Then, instead of executing the script attached to your node every frame, your main loop will go through all the nodes and run a function inside of their environment. You can also switch environments, so you can set the global environment to your node's env before executing it, and then switch back when you're done. This allows your scripts to use globals as they see fit, have them persisted between frames and excludes the possibility of name collisions or global namespace pollution. Additionally you can use metamethods to nest the node's environment inside the actual global environment or inside an API environment with helper methods (basically, if `__index` does not find something it looks it up in a `parent`).